# Debian 'bullseye' - no Terminal without GUI on Function Keys F1-F12

Tags: debian, terminal, administration

I had some serious problems with a Gnome upgrade from `3.32.0` to `3.34.0`. I missed out the upgrades done with `apt full-upgrade` and my gnome-shell did not start anymore.

However I wanted to fix this with a terminal being available on <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> in the old days and I was told it was moved to the keys <kbd>F3</kbd> and onwards.

However, it was not possible to reach this terminal with any of the Function-Keys from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd>. Is there a change been made away from those keys?

How do I reach this terminal without a need of a GUI?

```
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
            Kernel: Linux 5.2.0-3-686-pae
      Architecture: x86
```

Comment: Is `STRG` the same as `CTRL`? The key combination to reach a tty in my experience has been `CTRL+ALT+F(1-6)`.

Comment: @kemotep Yes, it's the same. `CTRL` is called `STRG` on german keyboards.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147128/change-default-tty-shortcut) might help.

Comment: @kemotep Yes, I fixed it. Thanks pointing it out!